# Dynamically filter app feed based on slide-out menu item selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate, feed

I have a prototype of an app that contains a feed `UITableViewController`.

The data to populate this feed comes from my model where I defined a Feed class that I pre-populate using the following data structure:

```
NSArray* data = @[@{const1:@"NSString1 for const1", const2:@"NSString1 for const2"},@{const1:@"NSString2 for const1", const2:@"NSString2 for const2"}, ..., @{const1:@"NSStringN for const1", const2:@"NSStringN for const2"}]; (total of N pairs of (const1, const2))
```

I created a slide-out menu view controller that is dynamically populated based on my data model as well.  As such I defined a slideOutMenuItems class that I also pre-populate using the following data structure:

```
NSArray* data = @[@"MenuItem1", @"MenuItem2", @"MenuItem3",... @"MenuItemP"]; (Total of P menu items)
```

When a menu item is selected by the user from the slide-out menu, I want to dynamically pass the menu item string (@"MenuItemM" if row number M is tapped on by the user) to filter out my feed based on matching the const1 NSString component of my feed array with the @"MenuItemM" NSString.

For that, in my slide-out menu view controller, in the prepareforsegue method, I have attempted the following:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    // Pass string based on SlideOutMenu cell selected to filter out feed

        if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Filter_MenuItem"]) {
            FeedVCTableViewController* flameVCTableViewController = (FeedVCTableViewController*) segue.destinationViewController;
            NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
            NSString *menuItem = [self.slideOutMenuItems menuItemAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSPredicate *pred =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name beginswith[c] %@", menuItem];
            flameVCTableViewController.feed = [[Feed prepopulatedFeed] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

        }

}
```

But I get the following error message on the last line of code above:

```
"No visible @interface for Feed declares the selector filteredArrayUsingPredicate".
```

Comment: Where is defined `prepopulatedFeed` in `Feed` class? How is defined `feed` in `FeedVCTableViewController`?

Comment: `feed` is a public property of type `Feed` in the `FeedVCTableViewController` class.  Its declaration in the .h file is as follows: `@property Feed *feed;`

Comment: `prepopulatedFeed` is a method implemented in the .m file of the `Feed` class:

Comment: `+ (instancetype)prepopulatedFeed {
    NSArray* data = @[@{const1:@"NSString1 for const1", const2:@"NSString1 for const2"},@{const1:@"NSString2 for const1", const2:@"NSString2 for const2"}, ..., @{const1:@"NSStringN for const1", const2:@"NSStringN for const2"}];
return [[self alloc] initWithJSONArray:data];
}
`